# The Rollback transaction request has no corresponding begin transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

i have used Save Transaction and rollback but still the same exception occur.

it gives me this error:

> Msg 3903, Level 16, State 1, Procedure HALAQATI_ttttttttttttt, Line
>   144 The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN
>   TRANSACTION.

Update

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure HALAQATI_ttttttttttttt, Line
>   160 usp_my_procedure_name: 102: Incorrect syntax near '='.

the stored procedure is :

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[HALAQATI_ttttttttttttt]
                @tf_commentparam nvarchar(100),
                @tf_secsuggdate int,
                @tf_testplace nvarchar(50),
                @tf_time nvarchar(7),
                @tf_day int,
                @an_id int,
                @ResponseText nvarchar(max) out,
                @ResponseNum int out -- (0 = everything is ok , 1 = error or wrong data)

AS
    DECLARE @startingTranCount int
    SET @startingTranCount = @@TRANCOUNT
Begin
SET XACT_ABORT ON
SET NoCount ON
    BEGIN TRY
    IF @startingTranCount > 0
        SAVE TRANSACTION mySavePointName
    ELSE
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            DECLARE @return_value_FIRST int,
                @tf_id int,
                @createddate int,
                @UnitIDFromStudentID int,
                @StudentIDFromAutoNominationID int

            set @createddate  = (select dbo.f_getHijNowByInteger());

            set @StudentIDFromAutoNominationID = (select st_id from tbl_autonomination where an_id = @an_id);

            set @UnitIDFromStudentID =  (select sec_id from tbl_secmsq where sm_id = 
                                        (select sm_id from tbl_ring where rg_id = 
                                        (select Ring_ID from HALAQATI_VIEW_GetAllStudents where Student_ID = @StudentIDFromAutoNominationID)))
                                        --/////////////////////////////////--
            DECLARE @return_value_SECOND int,@msg nvarchar(500)

            Declare @BranchNumFromAnID int = (select ne_branchno from tbl_nomineeexam where an_id = @an_id)
                                        --/////////////////////////////////--
            DECLARE @return_value_THIRD int
                                        --/////////////////////////////////--

    EXEC        @return_value_FIRST = [dbo].[sp_inserttestform]
                @tf_comment = @tf_commentparam,
                @tf_date = @createddate,
                @tf_secsuggdate = @tf_secsuggdate,
                @tf_testplace = @tf_testplace,
                @tf_unittype = 1, -- قطاع
                @tf_unitid = @UnitIDFromStudentID,
                @tf_id = @tf_id OUTPUT,
                @tf_userid = 10,--رقم جلال سعيد في التعليمية,
                @tf_type = 1, --آلي
                @tf_time = @tf_time,
                @tf_day = @tf_day,
                @tf_TFtype = 1 -- أجزاء

                if (@return_value_FIRST != 0 and @tf_id is null)
                begin

                    if (@return_value_FIRST = 1)        
                        begin
                            set @ResponseText  =  'أقل من يوم وأكثر من 15 يوم' 
                            set @ResponseNum = 1
                            return
                        end
                    else if (@return_value_FIRST = 2)
                        begin
                            set @ResponseText = 'لايوجد نقاط كافية للترشيح'
                            set @ResponseNum = 1
                            return
                        end
                    else if (@return_value_FIRST = 3)
                        begin
                            set @ResponseText = 'لم يتم ربط مركز الإشراف أو المجمع بمشرف لجان'
                            set @ResponseNum = 1
                            return
                        end
                    else
                        begin
                            set @ResponseText =  'هناك خطأ حاول في وقت لاحق' 
                            set @ResponseNum = 1
                            return
                        end
                                IF @startingTranCount > 0
                            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION MySavePointName
                        ELSE
                            ROLLBACK
                End

    EXEC        @return_value_SECOND = [dbo].[sp_insertAutoNominee]
                @tf_id = @tf_id,
                @st_id = @StudentIDFromAutoNominationID,
                @an_id = @an_id,
                @ne_branchno = @BranchNumFromAnID,
                @ne_userid = 10,
                @msg = @msg OUTPUT

                if (@return_value_SECOND != 0 or @return_value_SECOND is not null)
                    begin
                         --ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

                         if CHARINDEX('بنفس الفرع ونتيجته ناجح',@msg) > 0
                            begin
                                set @ResponseText  = 'لا يمكن إضافة ترشيح للطالب لأن له ترشيح سابق بنفس الفرع ونتيجته ناجح أو لم يختبر بعد'
                                set @ResponseNum = 1
                                return
                            end              
                         if CHARINDEX('خلال السبعة أيام',@msg) > 0
                            begin
                                set @ResponseText  = 'لا يمكن إضافة ترشيح للطالب لأنه غاب عن اختبار في نفس الفرع خلال السبعة أيام الماضية'
                                set @ResponseNum = 1
                                return
                            end                      
                         if CHARINDEX('خلال الأربعة عشر يوماً',@msg) > 0
                            begin
                                set @ResponseText  = 'لا يمكن إضافة ترشيح للطالب لأنه رسب في نفس الاختبار خلال الأربعة عشر يوماً الماضية'
                                set @ResponseNum = 1
                                return
                            end             
                                IF @startingTranCount > 0
                            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION MySavePointName
                        ELSE
                            ROLLBACK                    
                    end

    EXEC        @return_value_THIRD = [dbo].[sp_changeTFState]
                @tf_state = 4,
                @tf_id = @tf_id,
                @tf_chatsys = NULL,
                @tf_testdate = @tf_secsuggdate,
                @tf_time = @tf_time,
                @tf_day = @tf_day,
                @ne_cerprintdate = NULL

                IF @startingTranCount = 0

                    set @ResponseText = 'تم إعتماد و ترشيح الطالب إلى الإختبار بنجاح , وتم إرسال كافة البيانات إلى قسم الإختبارات في الجمعية'
                    set @ResponseNum  = 0
                    COMMIT
    END TRY
    --BEGIN CATCH
    --IF @startingTranCount > 0
    --  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION MySavePointName
    --ELSE
    --  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    --  set @ResponseText = ERROR_MESSAGE ()   
    --  set @ResponseNum = 1
    --END CATCH  
       begin catch
        declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @startingTranCount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @startingTranCount > 0
            rollback transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        raiserror ('usp_my_procedure_name: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
    end catch   
End
```

Comment: you've got a BEGIN  TRANSACTION then a ROLLBACK TRANSACTION , then a second ROLLBACK  TRANSACTION with no BEGIN - I'd start by looking there

Comment: @AndrewDeighton Ok, But how Do when i need to use more than Rollback in two Location of sp block ?

Comment: After the first ROLLBACK do you really want to the go ahead with the second operation?  If you don't, then you need to set a flag to avoid the second operation.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton but i break with **Return**

Comment: not if you get to the line IF @startingTranCount > 0, then you Rollback and continue, I thought

Comment: @AndrewDeighton I've Try That, but Facing another Problem, 


Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure HALAQATI_ttttttttttttt, Line 0
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118897/discussion-between-loai-and-andrew-deighton).

Comment: As a side note you should read this article and consider changing your prefixes (or dropping them entirely) to your procedures. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 3):

You cannot rollback in `CATCH` blocks w/o first consulting the state of [`XACT_STATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189797.aspx). Your catch block may execute *after* the transaction has rolled back (think, for instance, catching a deadlock).

See [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/) for a correct pattern:

```
create procedure [usp_my_procedure_name]
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    declare @trancount int;
    set @trancount = @@trancount;
    begin try
        if @trancount = 0
            begin transaction
        else
            save transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        -- Do the actual work here

lbexit:
        if @trancount = 0   
            commit;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback;
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        raiserror ('usp_my_procedure_name: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
    end catch   
end
```

Comment: Thanks for Xact_state info ..one question though ..will a deadlock rollback itself  before reaching the catch statement ?

Comment: When a deadlock is encountered the victim transaction is aborted and rolled back and only *after* the rollback is complete is the deadlock exception raised in the victim session.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Thanks, i don't why the problem still exist, i have change my Whole Catch with yours but another problem occur, I have update the Thread error

Comment: The Problem is that, inside this Stored procedure I'm calling 3 Stored Procedures, and each one of them has it's Transaction, is this responsible for that issue here ?

Comment: You can't simply rollback and return, how is the caller supposed to know if it can still commit or has to rollback or it was already rolled back? Think carefully how you mix exception, returns and transaction semantics, this is far from a trivial issue. My example is a pattern that works if *every* procedure follows it.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I've follow your example but the error now changed to **Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.**

Comment: You have an error in your logic, you begin and don't commit.

Comment: @RemusRusanu But I Commit My Trasnaction Like This 
    `IF @startingTranCount = 0
    COMMIT transaction`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118901/discussion-between-loai-and-remus-rusanu).